# Vuetify Vue 3 alias path have been changed

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have added to my vue 3 project vuetify via vue add.

This type of insertion
`<img src="@/assets/more-btn.svg" alt="" />` doesn't work, logs 404, shows path *localhost:8080/@/assets/more-btn.svg* instead of `<img src="/img/add-btn.7b3be03d.svg" alt="">`.

Kinda fixed it with `<img :src="require('@/assets/more-btn.svg')" alt="" />`.

How can i also add aliases, so everything was working as before? Any additions to add to aliases config?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the alias config to your vite config

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```